# Laravel 5.5 check Before making an insertion you make a get of your information If each service ID

Tags: laravel

Laravel 5.5 check Before making an insertion you make a get of your information If each service ID == 25, and this has to refuse the insertion and should say that it is complete

in my Controller

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
  //dd($request->all());
  $sj = new \App\Sejour;
  $pt= \App\Patient::findOrFail($request->input('pid'));
  $sj->date_sejour =date('Y-m-d');
  $sj->patient_id = $request->input('pid');
  $sj->service_id = $request->input('service_id');
  $sj->medecin_id = $request->input('medecin_id');
  $sj->categorie_patient_id = $pt->categorie_patient_id;
  $sj->assureur_id = $pt->assureur_id;
  $sj->type_prestation_id = $request->input('type_prestation_id');
  $sj->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
  $sj->save();

  return redirect()->route('sejour.show',$sj->id);
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get ?

Comment: no this not an error but i would like to do check Before an insertion and make a get information If each service ID == 25, and this has to refuse the insertion if each service >25 and should say that it is complete

Comment: Do you want to get information from "Sejour" Model about service Id? or you need some validation. Can you explain a bit more for this?

Comment: If the `$request->input('service_id')` is equal to 25 you will not insert the created Sejour? and if it's >25 what will you do the same if it is <25 what action you have to do

Comment: let me explain deeply i have table called service which has id | name | limit_patient
1 | ORL | 10
2 | pediatre | 15